# Unable to delete Mutiple Comp from listbox with Extendscript

Tags: extendscript

I can't perform multiple delette from my listbox although I made the listbox mutiselect Why ??
I need your help . You can see the full Script down there.

```
(function(){
   $.win = new Window("palette");
    var win = $.win;
    win.orientation = "column";
    win.alignChildren = ["center", "top"];
    win.spacing = 10;
    win.margins = 16;
    var listbox1 = win.add("listbox", undefined, undefined, { name: "listbox1", multiselect: true, columnTitles: "Max", showHeaders: true });
    listbox1.preferredSize.width = 136;
    listbox1.preferredSize.height = 208;
    var button1 = win.add("button", undefined, undefined, { name: "button1" });
    button1.text = "Search";
    var button2 = win.add("button", undefined, undefined, { name: "button2" });
    button2.text = "Delete";
    win.show();
    var myNewArray = [];
    button1.onClick = function Search() {
        var compsArray = new Array();
        var myProj = app.project;
        myNewArray = [];
        listbox1.removeAll();
        for (var i = 1; i <= myProj.numItems; i++) {
            if (myProj.item(i) instanceof CompItem) {
                myNewArray = compsArray[compsArray.length] = myProj.item(i);
                listbox1.add("item", myNewArray.name);
            }
        }
    }
    button2.onClick = function deletecomps() {  
        
      
for (var s = 1; s <= app.project.numItems; s ++) {
    if ((app.project.item(s) instanceof CompItem) && (app.project.item(s).name.match(listbox1.selection)))  {
        myComp = app.project.item(s);
        break;
        }
    }
       app.project.item(s).remove ();
    }
})();
```

[You can see an image to clarify the script in AE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crZ1R.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `listbox1.selection` in line 34

```js
if ((app.project.item(s) instanceof CompItem) && (app.project.item(s).name.match(listbox1.selection)))  {
```

is an array, and you're trying to match it to a string returned by `app.project.item(s).name` which is never going to match.

Also, what are you trying to achieve with the lines

```js
myComp = app.project.item(s);
break;
```

Here's the onClick function, but it works. It loops through the selection, and looks for a matching project item, based on the text of the listbox matching the comp's name. This is dangerous, because identical comp names would create false positives. I strongly suggest you don't use this technique in production code, because it will definitely cause problems for your users.

Also I'd turn the part wherre you populate the list into a separate function, and call it after you click delete, so that the list is refreshed, because at the moment the list stays the same, even after the comp is deleted.

```js
button2.onClick = function deletecomps() {  
        for (var b= 0; b < listbox1.selection.length; b++){  
            for (var s = 1; s <= app.project.numItems; s ++) {
                if ((app.project.item(s) instanceof CompItem) && (app.project.item(s).name.match(listbox1.selection[b].text)))  {
                    app.project.item(s).remove ();
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```